# Почему время вычислений в потоке main гораздо больше, чем в других?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Почему в приведенном коде время проведения аналогичных вычислений в разных потоках значительно отличаются?

```
public class qqq  {
    public static int result;
    public static final int COUNT = 1_000_000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Date start = new Date();
        while (result < COUNT)
           result++;
        Date end = new Date();
        System.out.println("main result = " + result + ". Calculated in " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + " ms");

        result = 0;
        MyFirstThread mft = new MyFirstThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(mft);

        start = new Date();

        t1.start();
        t1.join();

        end = new Date();
        System.out.println("t1 result = " + result + ". Calculated in " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + " ms");
    }

    public static class MyFirstThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            int t = 0;
            while (t < COUNT) {
                t++;
            }
            result += t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы неправильно считаете. По этому и неверные цифры. К тому же `System.out.println()` сама по себе довольно медленная операция. Если считаете, то считайте отдельно в каждом потоке и в РАВНЫХ условиях (сейчас у вас этого нет).

Comment: @Olmicron что вы имеете в виду, говоря про равные условия, буду признателен, если объясните более подробно.

Comment: В main для инкремента используется глобальная переменная result, из-за этого может тормозить. В потоке используется локальная переменная для инкремента что должно быть намного быстрее.